# How do I fix font corruption in Google Chrome 9.0.597.44beta in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, fonts, unicode

I am not sure what is causing this problem, but I think it is related to unicode problems. Google Chrome, seemingly out of nowhere a month ago, stopped rendering unicode characters in certain fonts. IE this

> ಠ_ಠ

Looks fine in some fonts, but looks like this in others. Renders fine in other browsers.

> [image: busted]

Most recently, I visited the FourSquare website and have complete font corruption. Here is IE vs Chrome

[image: IE vs Chrome text]

[Full Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxrJI.png)

What gives? Has anyone else seen this? How can I fix it?

Is this a known bug in Chrome?

Comment: I had an issue with some characters in v 8.0.552.224 (the current release) that was fixed with a restart of Chrome. I take it that this problem persists even after a restart.

Comment: @chrisF: yes, it persists after a restart and even after a reinstallation of chrome, as well as "portable" versions of chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to try :

1. This may be the same bug as this one :
   [Chrome sandbox blocks loading of fonts stored outside stock system locations](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29729).
   You can verify this by starting Chrome without the sandbox (--no-sandbox).
2. See this thread for similar problems and hints :
   [Anyone else having font issues with Mac version?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3d94b978196a300a&hl=en)
3. Try uninstalling Google Chrome Beta and installing the latest stable version.

Comment: Yes, I've installed the stable and the problem persisted.

Comment: I assume --no-sandbox didn't help?

Comment: Just tried it, --no-sandbox did not help.

Comment: See point 2 above.

Comment: Grumble. I had Adobe Type Manager installed. Based on the thread in point 2, which complains about typeface managers on Mac, I un-installed ATM and restarted and the problem went away.

Comment: I am happy this solved the problem. If it stays solved, just remember that answer-acceptance and bounty-awarding are 2 separate actions.

Comment: "I want my reputation god dammit"